# Strip/escape special characters from Google Spreadsheet field before passing data to Highcharts Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, google-sheets

I would like to have the numbers formatted in my Google Spreadsheet the following way in two series on yAxis of my highcharts graph:

$ 1,000,000.00

How do I strip/escape the $/,/.00 before the data gets passed to the graph?

Right now it just breaks the code so I have to use 1000000 on my spreadsheet.

Comment: Are you formatting the data as currency in the spreadsheet or are you literally typing in " $ 1,000,000.00". If you're literally typing in that text, then I'd suggest starting off by just typing in the number and formatting as currency. If you're already inputting the number and formatting as currency, we can see what we can do. Also, can we see some code to see what you're already doing?

Comment: Here is everything http://jsfiddle.net/p9nn8/. This includes the graph and the Google spreadsheet embed.

Comment: And I do format the numbers as currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I found is to create two separate spreadsheets.

Number 1 - Spreadsheet with formatting on it and etc.

Number 2 - Spreadsheet that takes IMPORTRANGE from spreadsheet #1 but no formatting. So after you import, just go Format -> Numbers -> Plain Text.

Works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set two additional arguments `decimaPoint, thousandsSep` in the [numberFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat) http://jsfiddle.net/p9nn8/9

Comment: I am actually trying to strip it from the spreadsheet before the data is passed to the graph. Not the other way around.

Comment: Whats the difference?

Comment: I want the numbers to be formatted on the spreadsheet ($1,000,000.00) but when I pass the formatted numbers to the graph it breaks the code.